# How do I use a variable as a class member instead of the default properties provided when calling the class?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

first of all, I sincerely apologize if the description of the question was too ambiguous or is asked using improper lingo.

Simply put, I am using a keyboard hook to recognize key input when the window is inactive. The key which is pressed is put into a text box. I would like to set the key value to whatever is in the text box:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For example, if I press "1", the text box value is set to D1, and a corresponding unicode value is assigned to a different variable. If I press "Q", the textbox value is set to "Q" with a corresponding unicode value assigned to another variable.

Say the value of textbox1 is "f1"

This is then assigned a value of "123", as the value for the f1 key is 123.

So when the f1 key is pressed, I want it to execute a certain portion of code like so:

```
myhotkey = keys.f1 'Assigns a value of "123" to myhotkey
If e.KeyCode = MyHotKey1 Then 'If the key "f1" aka "123" is pressed then
dosomeaction()
```

In order to have the program execute a certain portion of code based on what hotkey is entered, I currently have it assigning a myhotkey value like so:

```
Select case hotkey1    
Case is = "d1"    
myhotkey1 = keys.D1    'Sets the value of myhotkey1 to 49
Case is = "d2"    
myhotkey1 = keys.D2    'Sets the value of myhotkey1 to 50
Case is = "f1"    
myhotkey1 = keys.F1    'Sets the value of myhotkey1 to 123
Case is = "decimal"    
myhotkey1 = keys.Decimal    'Sets the value of myhotkey1 to 110
```

Instead of having to go through every single keystroke possibility within the user32 library, how can I assign a dynamic value to keys? When you call keys.   , it will bring up a paramater list which contains all available keystrokes and their corresponding value.

As an example, I would like to accomplish the following. Obviously this portion of code doesn't work, but I would like it to work in the same fasion as this would if it were proper syntax:

```
myhotkey1 = keys.(text1.text)
```

Comment: Instead of using the text box to hold a value, use it only for display. Store your Key value right away. How are you setting the text box value, anyway?

Comment: The textbox values are being assigned with a keyup event from the keyboardhook module.

Private Sub kbHook_KeyUp(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyUp
        Me.ActiveControl.Text = Key.ToString
    End Sub

Like so.

Comment: You should edit that into your question, not post in a comment. But I can tell you that *that* code is where you should be setting your variable.

Comment: Where I'm setting the variable really isn't of any relevance to what I'm trying to accomplish. I am aware that the value is currently being stored improperly in a textbox. It would contain the same value either way when being called.

Comment: Alrighty, then; I guess I completely misunderstood your question. I thought you were looking for a way to avoid a gigantic `select`. Sorry about that. Good luck.